# Redis connect ECONNREFUSED in NodeJS in Kubernetes cluster

Tags: node.js, kubernetes, redis

I am deploying a NodeJS server with 3 replicas and connect to **Redis** to use Sub/Pub function.

**NodeJS:**

```
const redis = require('redis');
const REDISPORT = 6379;
const subscriber = redis.createClient(REDISPORT, 'redis-service.default.svc.cluster.local');
const publisher = redis.createClient(REDISPORT, 'redis-service.default.svc.cluster.local');
```

**Error** in all three NodeJS pods:

```
Error: Redis connection to redis-service.default.svc.cluster.local:6379 failed - connect ECONNREFUSED 10.120.14.77:6379
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1141:16)
Emitted 'error' event on RedisClient instance at:
    at RedisClient.on_error (/usr/src/app/node_modules/redis/index.js:341:14)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/node_modules/redis/index.js:222:14)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:92:8)
    at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:60:3)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21) {
  errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '10.120.14.77',
  port: 6379
}
```

You can see when I use **'redis-service.default.svc.cluster.local'** in NodeJS pod, it will get my Redis service ip **10.120.14.77:6379** automatically.

And my **Redis** service ip is the same as **10.120.14.77:6379** when I check with "kubectl get svc redis"

```
- kubectl get svc redis
redis-service   ClusterIP   10.120.14.77   <none>        6379/TCP   74s

- kubectl logs redis
27 Sep 2020 08:41:20.309 # oO0OoO0OoO0Oo Redis is starting oO0OoO0OoO0Oo
```

**server-deployment.yml:**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: car-server-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 3
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: car-server
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: car-server
          image: gcr.io/PROJECT_ID/IMAGE_SERVER:TAG
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
              name: nodejs-port
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: car-server
```

**server-service.yml:**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: car-server-service
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 8080
      protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app: car-server
  type: NodePort
```

**redis-pod.yml:**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: redis
  labels:
    app: redis
spec:
  containers:
  - name: redis
    image: redis:5.0.4
    command:
      - redis-server
    env:
    - name: MASTER
      value: "true"
    ports:
    - containerPort: 6379
```

**redis-service.yml:**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: redis-service
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 6379
      protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app: redis
  type: ClusterIP
```

Comment: Edit the question to add output of `kubectl describe svc redis-service`

Answer (score 1):

Attempting for several hours and finally fix it. It is a small mistake when I create **kustomization.yml**. Therefore, basically not relevant to Redis or NodeJS.

Previous wrong file: **kustomization.yml:**

```
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization
commonLabels:
  app: my-app
bases:
- ./yaml
```

I put the commonLabels here and kustomize covered my Redis label and led to network error.

This is because I also used "**app label**" in my redis pod.

New file: **kustomization.yml:**

```
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization
bases:
- ./yaml
```